# how can we compare whether the result of an arithmetic operation is NaN or infinity..?

Tags: c#, double, nan, infinity

```
double SampleInterval = (PopulationValue - valueOfSignItems) / (SampleSize - noOfSignItems);
```

if my divisor = 0, sampleInterval wil bcom infinity and it will be = NaN if both dividend and divisor are = 0

i need to do my code when SampleInterval = infinity and in another context when SampleInterval = NaN.
How it is possible..??
can any one tel me how can i compare a decinmal value to infinity or to NaN.?

Answer (score 6):

You must use the Double.IsInfinity() and Double.IsNaN() methods.

```
if (Double.IsInfinity(SampleInterval))
{
  //TODO
}
if (Double.IsNaN(SampleInterval))
{
  //TODO
}
```

Don't compare directly to Double.NaN, it will always return false.

Comment: . Double.IsInfinity() doesnt handle -ve infinity, what we have to do for that..???

Comment: Weird. Double.IsInfinity should match +oo and -oo like said in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.isinfinity%28v=VS.90%29.aspx I tried and it works both with positive and negative infinity.

Answer (score 0):

Upping a old topic to add another solution (not really good looking but still worth the try if not working for -oo)

You can generate an -Infinity double by yourself, and use it as a comparison

```
double minusInfinity = -1.0/0.0;
if (yourDouble==minusInfinity ) {
    // yourDouble is equal to -oo
}
else {
    // yourDouble is not equal to -oo
}
```

You can do the same for +oo or NaN by using comparison :

```
double nan = 0.0/0.0;
double infinity = 1.0/0.0;
```